# How does fire from Starlight Dragonling work?

Tags: trove

The [description](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Starlight_Dragonling) of new Starlight Dragonling ally states:

> Damaging enemies has a chance to blast them in fire.

But I can't make it proc with my fae. Can anyone give more information about this? Like how often (approximately) does it proc? How much dmg it does? Is the effect (fire) visible?